# Can't chain multiple sed commands

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have four sed expressions chained up in one command, like so:

```
sed -e 's/.$//' -ne '/**#@+/ {p; r index.html' -e ':a; n; /**#@-*/ {p; b}; ba}; p' -e '/**#@+/d' input.txt > output.txt
```

However, the last one seems to fizzle (do nada). If I move it to the front of the chain, it executes correctly, but then my file is not how I want it to be (obviously).

Tested individually, all four commands work fine and do just what I want them to: replace a block of text with something else, get rid of the start & end markers and convert line-endings.

What's preventing the last command `-e '/**#@+/d'` from chaining?
It's all on CentOS 7.

Comment: Once you `p`, you can't `d` in the same sed command.

Comment: I see. wasn't aware of that. so the only way forward is to introduce another sed command with &&, right?

Comment: @choroba: I'm pretty sure that's not a good explanation, you can use `d`, it's just that it's meaningless to have it as the last command here, as it can't unprint what was already printed.

Comment: Can you simplify the sed-line?  
I think there is a way with a single sed, but I do not want to test it with your sed-line as given.  
Otherwise provide a minimal version of the index.html, explain in prose what sed is supposed to do and provide the expected result.