# sed: replace block of text between markers INCLUDING the markers themselves

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following sed commands that replace a block of text with the contents of a file between the start & end markers `/**#@+` and `**#@-*` respectively:

```
sed -i -ne '/**#@+/ {p; r block.txt' -e ':a; n; /**#@-*/ {p; b}; ba}; p' -e '/**#@+/d' test.txt && sed -i -e '/**#@+/d' -e '/**#@-*/d' test.txt
```

(Besides replacing text, the command also converts line endings.)

As it is, this leaves the start and end markers intact, but I want to get rid of those as well. [My using the `p` command means that I can't have a `d` command in the same execution unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271138/cant-chain-multiple-sed-commands). I work around the problem by introducing a second set of commands that delete those markers, but I would like to have it all in one single sed command, if possible.

**test.txt**

```
start of file

/**#@+
 * the start marker is above
 */
this should get replaced
/**#@-*/
end marker is above
```

**block.txt**

```
THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT
```

**Results**

Running the command should change test.txt like so:

```
start of file

THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT
end marker is above
```

**I am looking for the shortest, single-line solution in sed.**

Comment: please add sample input/output for testing

Comment: What you want us to try it on? A sample file would be helpful.

Comment: I've removed the line ending bit from the regex & included sample input, output and replacement files

Comment: `p` commands just print what is in the pattern space, they have no effect on the program flow. `d` deletes the pattern space and ends program flow, any commands following a `d` will not be executed (unless  a `b` or `t` command is directed to a `:` place holder that follows the `d` command).

Comment: @potong thanks for the explanation, good to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\/\*\*#@+/,/^\/\*\*#@-\*/cThis is the replacement' file
```

This changes the lines between the range to the required string.

To replace a range with contents of a file use:

```
sed -e '/^\/\*\*#@+/!b;:a;N;/^\/\*\*#@-\*/M!ba;r replacementFile' -e 'd' file
```

On encountering the start of the range set up a loop to gather up the range in the pattern space, then read the replacement file into the standard output and delete the contents of the pattern space.

Comment: just what I wanted, thank you so much. can't say I understood it all, especially the part with `M!ba;r`, but hey, it works

Answer (score 2):

Your start and end tags contain regex meta characters and `/`. `sed` only searches an input by regex and you need to escape `/` and all of those meta-characters in `sed`.

It is much easier to handle this in `awk` as `awk` allows non-regex plain text search also:

```
awk -v st='/**#@+' -v et='/**#@-*/' -v repl="$(<block.txt)" '
   $0 == st{del=1} $0 == et{$0 = repl; del=0} !del' file

start of file

THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT
end marker is above
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, but as stated I'm looking for a sed-only solution. The meta characters don't seem to have an effect on the commands: I don't filter for slashes and the replacement works fine.

Comment: Good luck with `sed`. Even though I can but don't want to promote *wrong tool* for this task.

Comment: btw to clarify about meta-characters further your `sed` is not actually searching full starting tag. e.g. `sed -n '/**#@+/p' file` will also find a line that is just `#@+` instead of full `/**#@+`

Comment: thanks, aware of the slashes. no biggie. also, sed is fine for me, can you mention how to solve this with sed? appreciate it.

Comment: See potong's answer and then you will understand better why I was avoiding `sed`